# Adding Event to Drop Down Field in Table Maintenance?

Tags: abap

I want to trigger some validation on select of an item in drop down field in SM30, based on that I want  to disable and enable some field.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create modification event for validation on Table Maintenance.    You can use **Maintenance event 01 Before saving the data in the database**  for validation, But validation on select item of dropdown is not possible in table maintenance. If you want validation on select of an item from dropdown list then i would recommend for creation of custom report program or module pool program.

Answer (score 1):

You should maintain the generated program.
SE80 --> Function Group --> screens --> {generated_screen_num}.
Treat it like any other program.